# OnItemClicklistener on list adapter that populate its items from database

Tags: java, android

I have a list view that implement swipelistadapter and app controller. The list view display correctly from the database, the only thing I need is to get position of each item and assign intent activity on each. These are my codes

```
public class SwipeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    private String[] bgColors;


    public SwipeListAdapter(Activity tab1, List<Movie> movieList) {
        this.activity = tab1;
        this.movieList = movieList;
        bgColors = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_serial_bg);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieList.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rows, null);

        TextView serial = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        serial.setText(String.valueOf(movieList.get(position).id));
        title.setText(movieList.get(position).title);

        String color = bgColors[position % bgColors.length];
        serial.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Below Class is the main activity

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private int index;
    private int[] images = new int[] { R.drawable.gallery1, R.drawable.gallery2, R.drawable.gallery3, R.drawable.gallery4, R.drawable.gallery5, R.drawable.gallery6, R.drawable.gallery7, R.drawable.gallery8 };
    ImageSwitcher switcher;
    android.os.Handler Handler = new Handler();

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private SwipeListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    private ListView listView;

   // private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";

    private String URL_TOP_250 = "http://192.158.33.172/locator/test/refractor.php?offset=";

    // initially offset will be 0, later will be updated while parsing the json
    private int offSet = 0;

    private static final String TAG = Tab1.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);


        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Adding request to request queue
//Editted        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new SwipeListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                        fetchMovies();
                                    }
                                }
        );


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                //String selectedFromList = (listView.getItemAtPosition(position).getString());
              //  String text = movieList[position];
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Tab2.class);
              //  i.putExtra("TEXT", text);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        switcher = (ImageSwitcher) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher1);
        switcher.setFactory(this);

        switcher.setImageResource(images[index]);
        switcher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                index++;
                if (index >= images.length) {
                    index = 0;
                }
                switcher.setImageResource(images[index]);
            }
        });
        switcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
        switcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out));

        //auto change image
        Handler.post(UpdateImage);

    }




    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        fetchMovies();
    }


    private void fetchMovies() {

        // showing refresh animation before making http call
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        // appending offset to url
        String url = URL_TOP_250 + offSet;

        // Volley's json array request object
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        if (response.length() > 0) {

                            // looping through json and adding to movies list
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject movieObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                    int rank = movieObj.getInt("rank");
                                    String title = movieObj.getString("postTitle");

                                    Movie m = new Movie(rank, title);

                                    movieList.add(0, m);

                                    // updating offset value to highest value
                                    if (rank >= offSet)
                                        offSet = rank;

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        // stopping swipe refresh
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // stopping swipe refresh
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }


    Runnable UpdateImage = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Increment index
            index++;
            if (index > (images.length - 1)) {
                index = 0;
            }
            switcher.setImageResource(images[index]);
            // Set the execution after 5 seconds
            Handler.postDelayed(this, (3 * 1000));
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        ImageView myView = new ImageView(getActivity());
        myView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        myView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(Gallery.LayoutParams.
                FILL_PARENT, Gallery.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return myView;
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What information are you trying to pass to the intent?

Comment: I suggest using the viewholder pattern for a long list of movies, it will increase the performance

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you show how the second activity will receive putExtra after clicking one of the item. App crash after clicking any of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Code for getting a single item:

```
String singleItem = getItem(position);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you show how the second activity will receive putExtra after clicking one of the item. App crash after clicking any of the item. –

Answer (score 0):

this is quite straight forward. here is a modification to your `onItemClickListener`:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            String text = movieList.get(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Tab2.class);
            i.putExtra("TEXT", text);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

just note that `movieList` object should be the same object you pass to your adapter

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you show how the second activity will receive putExtra after clicking one of the item. App crash after clicking any of the item.

Comment: Can you give an expression on how the onclicklistener will work with the next activity, cause app crashes after clicking any of the item.

Comment: @Webln please post the stacktrace to see what is going wrong

Comment: @Webln usually when app crashes logcat shows some error please double check